# ! operator used on pointers in C++

Tags: c++

I have the following While loop and I had a question regarding the syntax

1. The ! operator usually means not so does this mean the while loop will keep running until Exit is defined.

Wavplayback:

```
typedef struct
{
    struct {
        BOOL Seek_Active;
        DWORD Seek_Postion;

    }seek;
    CRITICAL_SECTION WavPlaybackCriticalSection;
    BOOL LoadNewFile;
    BOOL Pause;
    BOOL UnPause;
    BOOL Stop;
    BOOL Verify;
    BOOL Play;
    BOOL Initialise;
    BOOL Exit;
    BOOL Flush;
    BOOL ValidateHeaderData;
    void *Parent;
    void (*SetPageState)(LONGLONG Page, DWORD State);
}WAVPLAYBACK;
```

```
WAVPLAYBACK     *pPlayBack;
typedef int Exit;
```

```
while (!pPlayBack->Exit) 
{
//Executing some code
}
```

Comment: [`->` is higher precedence than `!`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), so `!pPlayBack->Exit` is equivalent to `!(pPlayBack->Exit)`.

Comment: What purpose do you think `typedef int Exit;` is serving in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct. They loop will exit when `pPlayBack->Exit` became TRUE by some external(other thread, etc.) or internal (inside the loop) reason.